# Should I write to MySQL slave (replica) for reporting?

Tags: mysql, replication, reporting, master-slave-replication

I intent to put reporting/analytics database on slave and run job scheduler every night to aggregate and insert data from operational database to reporting database.

Should I do this or I have to setup dedicated server for reporting/analytics database and use some tools to aggregate and insert data from slave to reporting server?

Thank for help,

Answer (score 0):

I would do the nightly aggregation into a Summary Table on the Master.  This abides by the principle that the Master and Slave are always in sync (within a slight delay).  It also allows for multiple slaves to share the read load.

Comment: My master node is quite busy so I set up a dedicated slave for reporting only and other slaves for other tasks.

Comment: Should we discuss how to make the Master less busy?

Answer (score 0):

Depends upon the criticality of Master and your wallet. If reporting queries are bothering much to Master, you may add a slave to it. If your business grows then chances of reporting might require different indexes created on main data hence you might need to handle different backup policies for Master and Analytics slave.

Answer (score 0):

**Replication in MySQL 8:**

[Source to Replica Replication](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-replication-primary-secondary-replication.html):

> The source is the primary, and there are one or more replicas, which
> are secondaries. The source applies transactions, commits them and
> then they are later (thus asynchronously) sent to the replicas. It is
> a shared-nothing system, where all servers have a full copy of the
> data by default.

[Replication](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/replication.html)

> Advantages of replication in MySQL include: Analytics - live data can
> be created on the source, while the analysis of the information can
> take place on the replica without affecting the performance of the
> source.

NOTE: Using the terminology has changed over time that "master - slave" are "primary (source) - secondary (replica)" respectively.

---

**The two scenarios:**

**(1)** slave (with operational db) --> job scheduler aggregate and insert to --> reporting db

Your replica has capacity to process and store for your reporting database. You can run the nightly job to read the database, process and insert into the reporting database. This will not affect your primary of your replica set. Once the reporting database data is created run the reports on it.

In this scenario, does the replica secondary has the capability (e.g., disk, memory and processor)? Will this fit in the existing setup that the replica also need to be updated with new data from the primary.

**(2)** slave (with operational db) -- tools aggregate and insert to --> reporting db (dedicated server)

You can run the tools to read the database (from the replica), process and insert into the reporting database on a dedicated server.

In this scenario, there is additional investment in a separate server and it means cost and maintenance are considerations. Also, where you run the tools is a consideration.